# Jetpack Compose How to Center an Item Vertically Respect to Another

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create the layout below by using box row and column. I know I can achieve this different ways like using constraint layout or creating custom layout however i want to know that is there any other ways simplier than these ways.

**What i want**

[image]

I tried someting but in the end they all gave me same result like below.

```
@Composable
fun Squares() {
Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(50.dp)
        .background(Color.Green)
    )
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}
}
```

**What i've tried**

[image]

How to place the green box center of the red box vertically? (I need a generic solution the box sizes are just for demonstration)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [**`alignBy`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/RowScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).alignBy(androidx.compose.ui.layout.HorizontalAlignmentLine)) modifier.

From the doc:

> Within a `Row`, all components with `alignBy` will align vertically using the specified `HorizontalAlignmentLines` or values obtained from `alignmentLineBlock`, forming a sibling group.

Using:

```
Row(){

   Box(modifier = Modifier
        .size(50.dp)
        .alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 2 }
        .background(Color.Green)
    )
    Column(Modifier.alignBy { it.measuredHeight / 4 }) {
        //....your code
    }
```

}

Then the 1/2 of the green `Box` (`it.measuredHeight / 2`) is vertically aligned with a quarter of the`Column` (`it.measuredHeight / 4` )

[image]

Comment: I'm curious why the OP wrote: I need a generic solution the box sizes are just for demonstration. And chose this as correct while this wouldn't work if the height of the red box is not the same as the height of the yellow box and the green is just half of it, would it? This only seem to work when you know the sizes before hand.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is more than one way but the simplest I can think of and knowing that the green box is of width 50 dp would be to use a spacer at the bottom and center vertically the row at the top:

```
@Composable
fun Squares() {
    Column {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
        Row {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(50.dp))
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: result]

Update:

If you don't know the width you can make use of onSizeChanged modifier to get it, sample:

```
@Composable
fun Squares() {
    var greenWidth by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(50.dp)
                    .onSizeChanged { size ->
                        greenWidth = size.width
                    }
                    .background(Color.Green)
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
        Row {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(greenWidth.pxToDp()))
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .background(Color.Yellow)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Int.pxToDp(): Dp = with(LocalDensity.current) { this@pxToDp.toDp() }
```

The result is the same but this way the preview could be wrong, it works at runtime.

Comment: Actually, I used the sizes as an example. Mostly I dont know the sizes of items. I need a generic solution.

Comment: oh, then there is more than one way as well, the simplest could be using .onSizeChange {} modifier to get the green space width and assign it to a variable and use it on the spacer width

Comment: Updated the answer using onSizeChange to get the width of the green area.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a `Layout` which does not incur a 1 frame penalty as the `onSizeChanged` does,

```
@Composable
fun TwoBoxes(
    box0: @Composable () -> Unit,
    box1: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        content = {
            box0()
            box1()
        }
    ) { measurables, constraints ->

        val looseConstraints = constraints.copy(
            minWidth =  0,
            minHeight = 0,
        )
        val placeable0 = measurables[0].measure(looseConstraints)
        val placeable1 = measurables[1].measure(looseConstraints)
        val height = max(placeable0.height, placeable1.height)

        layout(
            width = (placeable0.width + placeable1.width).coerceAtMost(constraints.maxWidth),
            height = height.coerceAtMost(constraints.maxHeight),
        ) {
            placeable0.placeRelative(
                x = 0,
                y = (height - placeable0.height) / 2,
            )
            placeable1.placeRelative(
                x = placeable0.width,
                y = (height - placeable1.height) / 2,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Sample]

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do it by using only Row and Column like this:

```
Column {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Green)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }

    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Transparent)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .background(Color.Yellow)
        )
    }
}
```